# Pizza Combinatorics Question

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many possible combinations of pizza,dips are there when?

- $4$ pizzas with up to $6$ toppings each, $10$ to choose from
- $4$ kinds of dip, $7$ to choose from

Each pizza cannot have the same topping multiple times. Ex- double pepperoni is not possible. Order of toppings does not matter. All $4$ pizzas and/or $4$ dips are allowed to be same.

---

Another question:

Given the equation: a+ 2b + c = 47

How many solutions are there when:

$a,b,c \ge0$

$a,b,c\ge1$

a, b, c are all integers

---

I am more interested in the way how to solve these problems than the answer. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It might be better to separate these two questions into different posts.  Also, I assume in the second question, you want $a$, $b$, and $c$ to be integers?

Comment: Yes I want a, b, c to be integers. I should've mentioned that. Otherwise the possibilities would be infinite

Comment: You should ask two separate questions.  In each question, you should include information about your own attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.